# Do Rust perform type casting in runtime or in compilation statically?

Tags: rust, casting

When playing with C or other programming languages, I always meet with the situation where types casting cannot be avoided, e.g. `let c_var = rust_var as u32`, and I feel I'm worried with the performance.

Does the type casting be performed in runtime or compilation? Is using `as` in-line not that performant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does the type casting be performed in runtime or compilation? Is using as in-line not that performant?

Generally depends whether there's a representation change. If there is, then there is necessarily a runtime component to the cast e.g. integer -> integer, integer -> float, float -> integer.

However, these conversions are commonly hardware operations possibly even hardware no-ops e.g. if you convert an u16 to an u32, on x64, the compiler will just store a u16 and read a u32 *from the same register*, possibly using a mov-with-zero-extend (depends of the semantics of the registers).

If you're worried, you can just look at what [godbolt](https://godbolt.org) outputs to get some hints or evidence. For instance:

```rust
pub fn conv(num: u16) -> u32 {
    num as _
}

pub fn conv2(num: u32) -> u64 {
    num as _
}
```

```
example::conv:
        movzx   eax, di
        ret

example::conv2:
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
```

because on x86 the 16-bit (and 8-bit) registers don't zero-extend, while the 32-bit registers do:

> - 32-bit operands generate a 32-bit result, zero-extended to a 64-bit result in the destination general-purpose register.
> - 8-bit and 16-bit operands generate an 8-bit or 16-bit result. The upper 56 bits or 48 bits (respectively) of the destination general-purpose register are not be modified by the operation. If the result of an 8-bit or 16-bit operation is intended for 64-bit address calculation, explicitly sign-extend the register to the full 64-bits.

So if the data "flows" right, the cast is a runtime no-op despite occurring at runtime (because it matches the default behaviour of the ISA), if it does not then an explicit operation might need to occur e.g. u16 -> u32 on ARM64 requires explicit zeroing of the upper 16 bits:

```
example::conv:
        and     w0, w0, #0xffff
        ret
```

because ARM was a 32b architecture from the very start, however that is not an issue for u32 -> u64:

```
example::conv2:
        mov     w0, w0
        ret
```

because not unlike x86 it zero-extends.